# what is AsyncStorage (react-native)?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

Can anyone explain how asyncStorage works ? Is it connected to database like SQLite or RocksDB ? Does asyncstorage write data to database directly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AsyncStorage is a simple, unencrypted, asynchronous, persistent, key-value storage system that is global to the app. It should be used instead of LocalStorage.

It's use full when you want to use some variable globally in App.
e.g like when you login first time in app the store the login id and password for next time it will take data from AsyncStorage and logged in successfully..

[Refer this link](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.39/docs/asyncstorage.html#asyncstorage)

Comment: So does asyncstorage interact with database ?

Comment: Yes,
On iOS, AsyncStorage is backed by native code that stores small values in a serialized dictionary and larger values in separate files. On Android, AsyncStorage will use either RocksDB or SQLite based on what is available.

Comment: Hi! our cybersecurity team have scanned our app and they detected as a possible vulnerability this AsyncStorage, because: it uses SQLite storing data unencrypted and it use sql statements without process before (to avoid an SQL injection). What can I do to justify that? Thanks in advance.